# Geting Current logged user details for jhi_persistenet_audit_event table

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

I am working with jhipster. I need to create a new table for auditing my database changes and link it with the default jhi_persistenet_audit_event table generated by the Jhipster. How I can  get the current logged user record from the jhi_persistenet_audit_event table to link that id to my new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solution 1: Principal principal

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", ""})
    public String start(Principal principal, Model model) {
           String currentUser = principal.getName();       
           return currentUser;
    }
```

---

> Solution 2: Authentication authentication

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", ""})
public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {
        return authentication.getName();
}
```

---

> Solution 3: SecurityContextHolder

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}
```

[Details 1](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-se) [Details 2](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security)