# How to access the information of the user who is currently accessing the controller in Spring and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I like to know who is currently going to the controller, and the controller will pull data from the database based on who the user is. Is there a way to find out who the user is or the username should be kept in the frontend of the application. I tried this in the controller.

```
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = "";
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        username = principal.toString();
    }
    System.out.print("email is:" +  username);
```

However, it returns anonymousUser, which is not a username in the database.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong. TIA

Comment: Are you logged in? because ```anonymousUser``` means you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

`((UserDetails) principal).getUsername()` will give *anonymousUser* when you access the endpoints without *sign-in*. To get the username you have to perform sign-in first and it will return the appropriate username. [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320534/geting-current-logged-user-details-for-jhi-persistenet-audit-event-table/55320919#55320919) ways to get details for currently logged-in user.